# Convert excel sheets to own files and delete first 8 rows

Tags: python, excel

I am using python to create a single file from each sheet in an excel ('xlsx') file. The first part works when i try to iterate through the files after they have been created in order to delete the first 8 rows i am having trouble using openpyxl. After creating the files how do i iterate through them and delete the first 8 rows?

```
import os
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlwt
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


path = 'C:\excelfiles'
targetdir = (path + "/New_Files/") #where you want your new files

if not os.path.exists(targetdir): #makes your new directory
    os.makedirs(targetdir)

for root,dir,files in os.walk(path, topdown=False): #all the files you want to split
    xlsfiles=[f for f in files] #can add selection condition here

for f in xlsfiles:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root, f), on_demand=True)
    for sheet in wb.sheets(): #cycles through each sheet in each workbook
        newwb = copy(wb) #makes a temp copy of that book
        newwb._Workbook__worksheets = [ worksheet for worksheet in newwb._Workbook__worksheets if worksheet.name == sheet.name ]
        #brute force, but strips away all other sheets apart from the sheet being looked at
        namer = targetdir + f.strip(".xls") + sheet.name + ".xlsx"
        newwb.save(namer.replace(',','')) 
        #saves each sheet as the original file name plus the sheet name

path2='C:/excelfiles/New_Files/'
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path2, topdown=False):
    xlsfiles2=[f2 for f2 in files]

for f2 in xlsfiles2:
    sheet = openpyxl.open(path2 + f2)
    sheet.delete_rows(7)
    book.save(f2.strip(".xlsx") + sheet.name + ".xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. First i needed to convert the files to .xlxs and then i could open using openpyxl.

```
path = 'C:\excelfiles'
targetdir = (path + "/New_Files/") #where you want your new files

if not os.path.exists(targetdir): #makes your new directory
    os.makedirs(targetdir)

for root,dir,files in os.walk(path, topdown=False): #all the files you want to split
    xlsfiles=[f for f in files] #can add selection condition here
for f in xlsfiles:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root, f), on_demand=True)
    for sheet in wb.sheets(): #cycles through each sheet in each workbook
        newwb = copy(wb) #makes a temp copy of that book
        newwb._Workbook__worksheets = [ worksheet for worksheet in newwb._Workbook__worksheets if worksheet.name == sheet.name ]
        #brute force, but strips away all other sheets apart from the sheet being looked at
        namer = targetdir + f.strip(".xls") + sheet.name + ".xls"
        newwb.save(namer.replace(',','')) 
        #saves each sheet as the original file name plus the sheet name
     

path2 = 'C:/excelfiles/New_Files/'
for root,dir,files in os.walk(path2, topdown=False):
    xlsfiles2=[t for t in files]

for p3 in xlsfiles2:
    
    wholename = getnamestringusingcityanddate(new_stringer,datefromname)
    pathandfilename = path2 + p3
    pathandfilenamexls = pathandfilename.replace('.xls','.xlsx')
    p.save_book_as(file_name= pathandfilename,dest_file_name=pathandfilenamexls)
    os.remove(pathandfilename)



for root,dir,files in os.walk(path2, topdown=False):
    xlsfiles3=[d for d in files]

for p4 in xlsfiles3:
    filepathcomplete= path2 + p4
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepathcomplete)
    sheenames = book.sheetnames[0]
    sheet = book[sheenames]
    sheet.delete_rows(1,8)
    sheet.delete_cols(11)
    sheet.delete_cols(5)
    date_style = NamedStyle(name='datetime', number_format='MM/DD/YYYY')
    for col in range(1,2):
        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            sheet.cell(row=row,column=col).style = date_style
    for col in range(10,11):
        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
            sheet.cell(row=row,column=col).number_format = '0.00'        
    book.save(filepathcomplete)  
    book.close()
```